# After running the Require.js Optmizer, JQuery plugin can't be used

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

This is my main.js. As you can see, it's very basic. I just require a jquery plugin.

```
//main.js
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min',
        underscore: 'lib/underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone: 'lib/backbone/backbone-optamd3-min',
        text: 'lib/requirejs/text',
        bootstrap_dropdown: 'lib/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown',
     }
});

require([
    'app',
    'bootstrap_dropdown', //LOAD THE JQUERY PLUGIN!!
], function(App){
    App.initialize();
});
```

This is my app.js

```
//app.js
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'router',
], function($, _ , Backbone, Router){
    var initialize = function(){
        $(function(){
            $("#menu_topbar").dropdown();
        });
        Router.initialize();
    }
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

When I run the site normally (without optimizing), everything works, and the dropdown plugin can be used.  But when I optimize, it says that it has `no method dropdown();`

For some reason that plugin is not loaded, which is weird. I look in my combined js file, and I see the plugin in there!

This is my build.js:

```
({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min',
        underscore: 'lib/underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone: 'lib/backbone/backbone-optamd3-min',
        text: 'lib/requirejs/text',
        bootstrap_dropdown: 'lib/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown',
    },
    baseUrl:'.',
    appDir:'./',
    dir: '../prod_js',
    optimize: 'none',
    optimizeAllPluginResources:false,
    findNestedDependencies:true,
    inlineText: true,
    modules: [
{
    name: 'main',
}
    ]
})
```

It's not only this plugin. I can choose any other plugin and it won't work.

I also tried require-jquery.js, which I am now using. Still the same problem.

When I put "alert('test')" inside bootstrap-dropdown.js, it does alert.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

Added "exclude: ['jquery']" to my app.build.js's module.